# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentUser.uid')]

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i get this warning when i try to store details to firebase using the currently logged in user.

i followed a online tutorial but i get this problem, is there any alternate method to use to achieve this?
i read about this problem but couldn't find a fix, i saw that its due to the user not being logged in but i did log in

```
var currentUser
class DecodeScreen extends Component {

  addToBorrow = async (booktitle, bookauthor, bookpublisher, bookisbn) => {

    currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser
    var databaseRef = await firebase.database().ref(currentUser.uid).child('BorrowedBooks').push()
    databaseRef.set({
      'title': booktitle,
      'author': bookauthor,
      'publisher': bookpublisher,
      'isbn': bookisbn
  })
  }

  state = {
    data: this.props.navigation.getParam("data", "NO-QR"),
    bookData: '',
    bookFound: false
 }
  _isMounted = false
 bookSearch = () => {
      query = `https://librarydb-19b20.firebaseio.com/books/${9781899606047}.json`,
      axios.get(query)
           .then((response) => {
               const data = response.data ? response.data : false
                   console.log(data)
                   if (this._isMounted){
                    this.setState({ bookData: data, bookFound: true })
                   }   
            })
  }
  renderContent = () => {
    if (this.state.bookFound) {
        return( 
          <View style={styles.container2}>

          <View style={styles.htext}>
          <TextH3>Title :</TextH3>
          <TextH4>{this.state.bookData.title}</TextH4>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.htext}>
          <TextH3>Author :</TextH3>
          <TextH4>{this.state.bookData.author}</TextH4>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.htext}>
          <TextH3>Publisher :</TextH3>
          <TextH4>{this.state.bookData.publisher}</TextH4>
          </View>

          <View style={styles.htext}>
          <TextH3>Isbn :</TextH3>
          <TextH4>{this.state.bookData.isbn}</TextH4>
          </View>

        </View>
        )
      }
      else {
        return(
          <View style={styles.loading}>
          <ActivityIndicator color="blue" size="large" />
        </View>
        )
      } 
 }


  componentDidMount(){
    this._isMounted = true
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false
  }
  render() {
    {this.bookSearch()}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderContent()}
        <Button title='Borrow' onPress={() => this.addToBorrow(this.state.bookData.title, this.state.bookData.author, this.state.bookData.publisher, this.state.bookData.isbn)} />
    </View>
  );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not a promise, and you can't `await` it.  It's [either null or a user object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth?hl=en#currentuser).

Second, it's not guaranteed to be populated with a user object on immediate page load.  You will need to use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to know when the user object first becomes available after a page load.

Comment: oh okay how will that change be made in my code? im sorry im new i quite dont understand how to make that change.